# How can I convert UTF-8 to escaped string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got
`u'≈'.encode('unicode_escape')`

I want to receive "\u2248" as string.

Comment: `u'≈'.encode('unicode_escape').decode()`

Comment: also `u` prefix is redundant in Python 3 and added for [easier migration from Python 2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov ok. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured out a way to do that. You can do `.decode('ascii')` right on the string, then it will give you back the encoded string, for example:

```
"".encode("unicode_escape").decode('ascii')
```

gives you

```
'\\U0001f642'
```